# Swift Nested Calling

Tags: swift3

```
class BFCommon {
    class BFUser {

    }

    extension BFUser {
        static func sayHello() {
            print("Hello")
        }
    }
}

BFCommon.BFUser.sayHello
```

Need help fixing my code to call a function like so.

BFCommon.BFUser.sayHello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as the error message suggests, extensions can only be declared at the file scope:

```
class BFCommon {
    class BFUser {}
}

extension BFCommon.BFUser {
    static func sayHello() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}

BFCommon.BFUser.sayHello()
```